# What's the "normal" opposite of flautando?

Tags: notation, composition, sheet-music, string-instruments

I'm writing a piece in which I need string instruments to switch regularly between flautando and normal timbre. How do I denote this? Basically, I need a word which means "normal" with regard to where the bow falls.

Answer (score 14):

Normale (norm.) or ordinario (ord.) are the standard methods for marking a return to regular articulation after using an alternative technique.

Answer (score 10):

In doubt, you can always negate a specific playing instruction by mentioning it with a *non* prefix. In this case I'd probably write *non flaut.*, if in your context *ord.* would not be clear enough.

Alternatively you could consider what particular sonic quality of “normal bowing” you want to contrast against flautando. Should it be the robust sound and attack? You might alternate between *flautando* and *pesante*. You want the opposite of the sweet airiness of a flautando? You could alternate between *sul tasto* and *sul ponticello*. Etc. etc..

Answer (score 2):

In such cases, the notation *arco* is typically given to request that the performers play with standard technique.

So just as you specify *flautando* for some portions, simply specify *arco* for the other portions.

Comment: This is not the standard notation method, though most performers would probably understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: I would stick with *ord*.   *Arco* is pretty much reserved for not-pizzicato,  and occasionally for  not-colLegno.

Comment: @Peter (and Carl): Thanks for the information! I'm not a string player, so I always assumed *arco* simply meant "normal." Today I learned!

Comment: As a violin player I would say do *not* type *arco* when you are alreadu using the bow, *arco* is Italian for bow. The term *ord.* is the standard indicating a return to ordinary playing after playing a special effect.